# Why does my Authorize attribute only work on the client and not in the controller

Tags: .net, authentication, blazor, authorization, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM project with a Client, Server and Shared project.

**Problem**

When I make a Post request to my controller it doesn't want to enter the `ActionResult` if I add the `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` attribute (even if I'm logged in). However if I add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute it works just fine.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostOutput")]
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostOutput([FromBody] string json)
...
```

But in the client it works fine either way (as long as I login first)

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
...
```

Using that it can access the page if I login first just as you'd expect, heck it even works when I add this attribute to the page `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "User")]`. So everything works as expected on the Client side, but not on the server for some reason.

Is there something super obvious that I've missed here?

**Project Setup**

The way I've setup the client is like this

**Program.cs (Client)**

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IDashboardService, DashboardService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

With the `CustomAuthorizationHandler` looking like this

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private ISessionStorageService _sessionStorageService;

    public CustomAuthorizationHandler(ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService)
    {
        _sessionStorageService = sessionStorageService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var jwtToken = await _sessionStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("UserSession");
        if (jwtToken != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

}
```

And the `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider`

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorageService;
        private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService)
        {
            _sessionStorageService = sessionStorageService;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var userSession = await _sessionStorageService.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSessionModel>("UserSession");
                if (userSession == null)
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
                }

                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }, "JwtAuth"));

                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }
        }

        public async Task UpdateAuthenticationStateAsync(UserSessionModel userSession)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
            if (userSession != null)
            {
                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }));

                userSession.ExpireDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(userSession.ExpiresIn);
                await _sessionStorageService.SaveItemEncryptedAsync("UserSession", userSession);
            }
            else
            {
                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
                await _sessionStorageService.RemoveItemAsync("UserSession");
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }

        public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                var userSession = await _sessionStorageService.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSessionModel>("UserSession");
                if (userSession != null && DateTime.Now < userSession.ExpireDateTime)
                {
                    result = userSession.Token;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

**SessionStorageServiceExtension.cs**

```
public static class SessionStorageServiceExtension
{
    public static async Task SaveItemEncryptedAsync<T>(this ISessionStorageService sessionsStorageService, string key, T item)
    {
        var itemJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
        var itemJsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(itemJson);
        var base64Json = Convert.ToBase64String(itemJsonBytes);
        await sessionsStorageService.SetItemAsync(key, base64Json);
    }

    public static async Task<T> ReadEncryptedItemAsync<T>(this ISessionStorageService sessionsStorageService, string key)
    {
        var base64String = await sessionsStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(key);
        var itemJsonBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        var itemJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(itemJsonBytes);
        var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(itemJson);
        return item;
    }
}
```

And the **Program.cs (Server)**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default") ?? throw new NullReferenceException("No connection string in config!");
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JwtAuthenticationManager.JWT_SECURITY_KEY)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserAccountService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<CoverAIDbContext>((DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
var app = builder.Build();
```

**Edit**

Calling this from the page made it work

```
var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider;
var token = await customAuthStateProvider.GetToken();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
{
    Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
    using var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Product/PostOutput", serializedString);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    _output = "Error.";

    loading = false;
     buttonText = "Generate";

     _output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Which I find strange because this didn't work, even though `jwtToken` is valid. I have no idea what's going on here.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private ISessionStorageService _sessionStorageService;

    public CustomAuthorizationHandler(ISessionStorageService sessionStorageService)
    {
        _sessionStorageService = sessionStorageService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var jwtToken = await _sessionStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("UserSession");
        if (jwtToken != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", jwtToken);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

}
```

So doing this in the Client doesn't work

```
[Inject]
public IDashboardService DashboardService { get; set; }

async Task Generate()
{
    ...
    string serializedString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(postBody);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
    {
        using var response = await DashboardService.Generate(serializedString);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            _output = "Error.";

         _output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    
}
```

But this works

```
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@inject HttpClient Http

async Task Generate()
{
    ...
    string serializedString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(postBody);


    var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider;
    var token = await customAuthStateProvider.GetToken();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
    {
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        using var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Product/PostOutput", serializedString);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            _output = "Error.";

        _output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may have missed something (which I often do), but you don't appear to have provided information on the owner of the last block of code, It looks like a class that inherits from `HttpClient`, but that's a guess.  If so, it may be helpful to provide it in your question.  Also,  is `Http` in the previous code block the standard or custom `HttpClient`.

Comment: Good thinking! I've updated the question and it should be correct now, let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this code correctly, you treat the `UserSession` key value as different entities in the two code paths.

Using the generic HttpClient, you get the token from the `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` by calling `ReadEncryptedItemAsync`.  This returns a `UserSessionModel` object from the `UserSession` value.

```cs
// CustomAuthenticationStateProvider 
// GetToken
var userSession = await _sessionStorageService.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSessionModel>("UserSession");
```

You then get the token from the returned `UserSessionModel` object.

```cs
// CustomAuthenticationStateProvider 
// GetToken
var userSession = await _sessionStorageService.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSessionModel>("UserSession");
//...
result = userSession.Token;
```

While in the Typed HttpClient, `CustomAuthorizationHandler` gets the token from the `ISessionStorageService` using the method `GetItemAsync` to get `UserSession` as a string.  You treat this as the JwtToken.

```cs
//CustomAuthorizationHandler 

var jwtToken = await _sessionStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>("UserSession");
```

`UserSession` can't be both a `UserSessionModel` and a `JwtToken` string.